# Pass a Python ArgumentParser to another module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this Python code in `main.py`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("subname", help="Name of subreddit")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then in another file `speciallogger.py`:

```
import logging
import time

from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
path='logs/log_SUBNAMEHERE_logger.txt'
logmsg = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
fmt = u'%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(filename)s:%(lineno)d\t%(message)s'
logmsg.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path, when="d", interval=1, backupCount=14)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
logmsg.addHandler(handler)
```

The script (starts with `main.py`) executes via a cron using an argument.

I need to pass that argument to `speciallogger.py` so I can name the filename what subname is, along with ensuring `logmsg` can be used across all modules without the log file being recreated each import during a script using multiple modules.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function in `speciallogger.py` and call that function right after doing the arg parsing.

> `speciallogger.py`

```
import logging
import time
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

def initialize(subname):
    path = f'logs/log_{subname}_logger.txt'
    logmsg = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    fmt = u'%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(filename)s:%(lineno)d\t%(message)s'
    logmsg.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path, when="d", interval=1, backupCount=14)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
    logmsg.addHandler(handler)
```

> `main.py`

```
import speciallogger
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("subname", help="Name of subreddit")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    speciallogger.initialize(args.subname)
```

---

`logging.getLogger()` will return the same logger object no matter *where* in the program it's called, per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger):

> "All calls to this function with a given name return the same logger instance. This means that logger instances never need to be passed between different parts of an application."

Thus, when you modify it by doing `setLevel` and `addHandler`, you're making a persistent change that should reflect across the entire program.

Comment: I've tried this, but in main.py it gives the error `NameError: name 'logging' is not defined`. How am I meant to log lines in main.py?

Comment: @Zeno you would log things the same way as before. Import `logging` and use it as normal (call `getLogger("Rotating Log")` to make sure that you're using the same logger you modified during initialization).